# Google remarketing tag to Measurement protocol

Tags: google-ads-api, measurement-protocol

I am using the following remarketing tag on the ecommerce sites provided by Adwords:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var google_tag_params = {
ecomm_prodid: "REPLACE_WITH_STRING_VALUE",
ecomm_pagetype: "REPLACE_WITH_STRING_VALUE",
ecomm_totalvalue: REPLACE_WITH_STRING_VALUE
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = xxxxxxxx;
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
var google_remarketing_only = true;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/xxxxxxxx/?value=0&guid=ON&script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

In some cases (user added a product to the cart, user made an order) I am using webhooks to inform about the actions and it is necessary to send the remarketing data server side. My question is how does the remarketing tag look like using Measurement protocol?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do here. Measurement Protocol is a Google Analytics feature while remarketing tags are for Adwords. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @dorian I was trying to find a way how to send remarketing tags from the server and I've found Measurement protocol as a recommendation how to do so. Do you know about any other way how to send remarketing tags server-side? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see. If you absolutely have to stay server-side, then the Measurement Protocol route could work in combination with Dynamic Attributes. It's going to be a much more complicated setup, though. I'd recommend checking if you really can't use the client-side tag.